# Trigger para bloquear inserción

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Estoy tratando de crear un trigger que me bloquee la insercion depende del producto, es decir en la base de datos solo pueden ingresar ciertos productos y otros no. 
Este es el trigger .

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_PTS_Bloqueados2020] ON
[dbo].[tblmvtoinventarios]
after insert , update, delete 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @codtipomvto VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @codigo VARCHAR(20)




SELECT  @codtipomvto = T0.codtipomvto , @codigo = T1.codigo
  FROM  tblencinventarios T0
    INNER JOIN INSERTED T1 ON T0.consecutivo = T1.consecutivo
      IF (  @codigo LIKE 'PT-%' AND @codtipomvto IN ('E104','S104')) 
       OR (  @codigo LIKE 'PTD-%' AND @codtipomvto IN ('E104','S104'))
       OR (  @codigo LIKE 'PV-%' AND @codtipomvto IN ('E104','S104') and @codigo NOT IN ('PV-03347','PV-03392'))  

       BEGIN 
            RAISERROR ('No se admite este movimiento' , 16, 1 ) 
            ROLLBACK   
       END
END
GO
```

El funciona, y bloquea los movimientos en el inventario. pero de un momento a otro al facturar algun producto se dispara y no permite hacer el movimiento , cuando unicamente deberia bloquear la insercion al inventario.

Comment: El trigger tiene otro problema que previene manejar varias filas a la vez. Fuera de eso, no veo como esté fallando.

Comment: Entiendo, estuve analizando un poco acerca de ese Trigger lo que deduci fue que cuando facturan y hacen otro movimiento , el toca esos conceptos, por lo que la solucion por el momento es crear uno por cada uno, de esa manera no falla ni afecta la produccion,